# GtkWarning: _gtk_tree_view_column_autosize: assertion `GTK_IS_TREE_VIEW (tree_view)' failed

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I get error:

```
GtkWarning: _gtk_tree_view_column_autosize: assertion `GTK_IS_TREE_VIEW (tree_view)' failed
```

after I changed column sizing from grow only to automatic in my tree view.

Here is the [ui file](https://github.com/umpirsky/revision-monitor/commit/03bf82d21742346f83c378ea0337da4dc2a3ba78#data/ui/RevisionMonitorWindow.ui).

Any idea?

Comment: Um, does this actually cause any problems? It's just a warning, AFAIK the program should keep running. No idea what causes it, though.

Comment: No, but I would like to fix it :)

Comment: Can you make a minimal example that produces the warning? If not, then you should be able to figure out how to fix it. If so, then it's probably a bug and you should report it to bugzilla.gnome.org.

Comment: @ptomato You pointed me in right direction, thanks. While making a minimal example, I found the reason why this warning occurs, but I still don't understand why. Here is the fix https://github.com/umpirsky/revision-monitor/commit/117de4df6d88531c2885fa791519989140f39f01. Looks like min_width can't be used with autosize.